# How do I set the id of the form in Zend_form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to set the id of the form, I can set the id of its elements okay.

```
class Form_Purchase extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_id = 'purchase';

    public function init()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

didn't work!

All I got was...

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<dl class="zend_form">
....
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code (put this line into the init method):

```
$this->setAttrib('id', $_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your case you can use the form name as the id, you could use this too, again in your init.

```
$this->setName($_id);
```